# Does a U.S. District judge's decision set binding horizontal precedent in the same district?

Tags: united-states, jurisdiction, common-law, precedent

Suppose a U.S. district judge in, say, the Southern district of New York writes a decision regarding some legal procedure. Can a different U.S. district judge in the same district write a contradictory decision? Or must he/she respect the precedent of the previous decision even though it did not come from a higher court?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Precedent at the same level in the court hierarchy’s non-binding

Only lower courts are bound.

Comment: But an exception to this might be "law of the Circuit"?

Comment: Federal circuit courts can override their own precedent

Comment: @DaleM : I wonder if your comment above should be a part of the answer.